# How get equation after fitting in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to use [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) for calculating the equation of some data.  I used this code to fit a curve to my data:

```
svr_lin = SVR(kernel='linear', C=1e3)
y_lin = svr_lin.fit(X, y).predict(Xp)
```

But I don't know what I should do to get the exact equation of the fitted model.
Do you know how I can get these equations?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.svm import  SVR
boston = load_boston()
X = boston.data
y = boston.target
svr = SVR(kernel='linear')
svr.fit(X,y);
print('weights: ')
print(svr.coef_)
print('Intercept: ')
print(svr.intercept_)
```

the output is:

```
weights: 
[[-0.14125916  0.03619729 -0.01672455  1.35506651 -2.42367649  5.19249046
  -0.0307062  -0.91438543  0.17264082 -0.01115169 -0.64903308  0.01144761
  -0.33160831]]
Intercept: 
[ 11.03647437]
```

And for a linear kernel, your fitted model is a hyperplane (**ω**^[T] **x**+ b = 0), where **ω** is the vector of weights and b is the intercept.

Comment: thank you. its work for linear kernel.
what about other kernels like exponential or polynomial

Comment: The equation of all `sklearn` kernels are here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#svm-kernels. For other kernels `gamma`, `degree` and `coef0` are selected by user or by hyperparameter optimization (e.g. using a `GridSearchCV`). Please look at `sklearn` documentation. For instance, the documentation for SVC is here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html

Comment: i try for poly kernel but i cant find any thing in document about calculate equation. can you explain more about calculate polu equation?

Comment: In 2d, it looks like (x+coef0)^degree. You either specify the coef0 and degree when you are initiating your estimator or you need to perform a hyperparameter optimization (e.g. GridSearchCv) to find them.